# Using argparse, how do parse command line arguments to specify variable values?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

With multiple functions, how to I code such that I can input values for the function variables to get a result?

```
def sum(i, j):
      return i+j

def totalsum(k):
      return sum(a, b) + k

print totalsum(c)
```

Command line prompt

```
python gendata.py -–a=1 –-b=2 –-c=3
```

Comment: the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: I think you probably want your second function to take three arguments, unless I don't understand you.

Comment: Why does `sum` ignore its arguments and return the sum of two globals?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your usage of functions, but here is an adaptation of your program (based on the best of my ability to what you are trying to accomplish):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('a', type=int)
parser.add_argument('b', type=int)
parser.add_argument('c', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

def sum(i, j):
      return i+j

def totalsum(k):
      return sum(args.a, args.b) + k

print totalsum(args.c)
```

Usage:

```
python script.py 1 2 3
6
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the command line to input values for the function parameters, this is a simplified version for the functions

Comment: Updated it appropriately.

Comment: I got this..
usage: myScript.py [-h] a b c
myScript.py: error: too few arguments

Comment: Interesting, because it works on my machine... Um, I don't know atm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--a", type=int)
parser.add_argument("--b", type=int)
parser.add_argument("--c", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.a, args.b, args.c)
```

Comment: `parser.add_argument("--a", type=int)`